# Distance Between TextView and ImageView

Tags: android, android-layout, view, android-relativelayout

This is the Layout of a Fragment(attach on the main Activity):

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.carbos.user.nameapp.Class"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView
        style="@style/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/title"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/desc"
        android:layout_below="@id/image"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

But the distance between TextView and ImageView doesn't 0dp and there isn't `@id/desc`. 
This is the output(the image and title is for example) :

[image]

This is the image in Drawable:
[image]

How can i set the distance between TextView and ImageView( and TextView of `@id/desc`)? I tried with LinearLayout, but it doesn't work

Comment: Can you include here the actual image file going into that ImageView?

Comment: First, RelativeLayout doesn't have an orientation attribute, so `android:orientation="vertical"` is useless here. Second how/where are you getting the image and what's its height?

Comment: Can you post your @style/title file?

Comment: in @style/title i only set the height of Title (30sp)

Comment: I saw the image and forgot the question.

Comment: if you add ScrollView as a parent (then RelativeLayout), can you scroll and see the text underneath the image?

Comment: You could try a few of the [`android:scaleType`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html) attributes and see whether the image renders correctly (in particular, `android:scaleType="fitXY"`) (*Edit:* Also, the code where you set the image could be useful)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try changing the ScaleType of the ImageView to something else. Probably CenterCrop. For more information see: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

Comment: Thanks, this is the solution, but with CenterCrop is not right, i will use the other, thanks ;)

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that there is no distance between textview and imageview. The gap you see is the white space in the image.
To check this theory, try setting imageview background instead of source.

Comment: I don't understand, ImageView has a background? And how can i set this (from XML)?

Comment: android:background="@drawable/YOUR_IMAGE"

Comment: Or from java

    imageView.setBackground(R.drawable.YOUR_IMAGE);

Comment: Oh right, with background the ImageView is in space white too, i will use scaleType

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.carbos.user.nameapp.Class"
android:orientation="vertical">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<TextView
    style="@style/title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dip">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/title"/>
 </RelativeLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/desc"
    android:layout_below="@id/image"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```